# Вытянуть данные из адресной строки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Задача:
в адресной строке браузера введено: `site.ru/text` .
мне нужно с помощью php вывести на страницу текст который идет после */*, тоесть `text`
Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете добавить в файл `index.php` (который находится в корне сайта) следующие строчки:

```
$path = preg_replace('/^\/index.php/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

echo($path);
```

**UPD**:

Код выше будет выдавать правильную строку для запросов вида `site.ru/index.php/test`.

Для того, что бы заставить Apache перенаправлять все запросы на `index.php` вам нужно добавить следующие строки в `.htaccess` файл:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Учтите, что вам так же понадобится включенный `mod_rewrite` на сервере.

Comment: Ваш код работает только для запросов вида site.ru/index.php/test. При использовании реврайта в строке $path = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']; выдается: Notice: Undefined index: PATH_INFO

Comment: @Visman, вы правы. Отредактировал ответ.

Comment: То есть мой ответ все-таки более точный чем ваш :)

Comment: Ваш ответ не будет работать для запросов вида `site.com/test` без включенного `mod_rewrite`. А в остальном да, ваш точнее :)

Comment: Из самого вопроса уже проистекает, что переадресация есть в наличии. Иначе он спрашивал бы не про php.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте переменную $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]. Возвращает то что вам надо + GET параметры из строки запроса.

Полное описание массива $_SERVER тут: http://php.net/manual/ru/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: а как получить это без `/` , а все что после него?

Comment: @Денис , например воспользовавшись функцией substr http://php.net/manual/ru/function.substr.php